# How can I roll N dice in constant time and preserve a binomial distribution?

Tags: optimization, random

If I want to throw a 100d6, I have to:

```
int sum=0;
for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
    sum += Random.BetweenInclusive( 1, 6);
```

But for high dice count it may be expensive.

Does there exist any algorithm that is able to throw many dice with an algorithm that always require the same time (it is CONSTANT in the number of dice) and that will still produce a binomial distribution?

The goal is to write a function that:

```
int RollADice( int rolls, int faces)
{
    if( rolls <1245) // constant determined by profiling
    {
        int sum=0;
            for(int i=0; i<rolls; i++)
                sum += Random.BetweenInclusive( 1, faces);
        return sum;
    }
    else
    {
        return RollArbitraryDice( rolls, faces); // how would be that function?
    }
}
```

The only progress so far is throwing 2 dice at the same time (by noting that the distribution of 2 dice is a linear ramp, so we could cut the ramp in the middle and get a rectangle).

I also found an algorithm that does roll many dice [preserving entropy](http://nullprogram.com/blog/2009/08/28/), but it actually have a cost that is binomial on number of dice, not really a good trade (unless you need entropy).

Comment: I dont think it statistically makes sense  to roll multiple times and then sum it up. What problem are you actually trying to solve with this?

Comment: `return rolls * Random.BetweenInclusive( 1, faces )`? More seriously I do not believe you can have a constant time if you want to really simulate all the rolls, you need to fake it at some point

Comment: @wondra In RPGs most skills roll several dices to determine stuff like damage etc. I think that most games just roll multiple times, then problem is that when the skills rolls too many dices this cause lag in mobile games.

Comment: @realUser404 I want to keep original distribution, if possible, multyplying by rolls is a linear distribution not a binomial. (the binomial function is even slower unluckily, and I'm not sure I'm rounding it correctly anyway).

Comment: You'd have to roll so many dice to notice how long it takes, that I'm sure that this isn't a problem. Even for ShadowRun.

Comment: Well, just for the sake of knowing it. It is a clicker game where each tile in a map produce a number of resources that is XdY. As you know in clicker games stuff grow exponentially (I already have a limit-less integer number to store the correct sum of everything, and surprisingly, it takes somewhat the 0.5% of time, the profiler show the lag depends on the many roll of dices. I roll dices because they are nice for a gameplay question, but as long as you reach million dices that start to become a problem ^^.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rolling dices approaches a normal distribution as explained in this answer : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397689/why-convolution-regularize-functions/398146#398146

So for n > 1245 I believe you can safely use that distribution!

You can then just generate a random number in that distribution using the [Muller Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform)

Comment: Nice Transform :) I think it is actually used in implemenation of some normal distributions?

Comment: @DarioOO Yes, many implementations of normal distribution are rely on this, especially on Marsaglia's Polar variant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marsaglia_polar_method

Comment: @DarioOO I discourage using own implementations, if one is in math library or standard, you should always prefer these. I am speaking from personal experience from implementing one of such generators - it is not trivial to make a good one.

Comment: I know to not reinvent the wheel, the fact was I didn't know there was already a standard function for that :)